# Is it possible to block Android Wear devices from installing the app?

Tags: android, google-play, android-manifest, wear-os

[**My app**](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.lb.app_manager) is really not ready to be installed and used on Android Wear (really small screens - smart watches), yet some users installed it. I know this because I've tested it on an emulator, and it doesn't look good at all.

I do not want users to get frustrated that they found an app that they can run there, yet when they install it, it doesn't work well.

Is it possible to block Android-wear devices from installing apps? If so, how?

Now that I think about it, how does Android-Wear devices even install apps?

Comment: You can install any app on Android Wear with ADB using bluetooth debugging. So, the average person isn't going to install your app on their smartwatch. I wouldn't be concerned.

Comment: @JaredRummler I don't understand. How does the average user install apps on Android-wear then? And how do apps tell the OS that it's ok to install it on Android-wear ? Also, how come I've noticed users use a different, much more popular app on Android-wear?

Comment: Are you sure that they are running it on Wear, not just a very-small sized Android devices that look like a watch?

Comment: @atok The developer console says some users have it installed on Android 4.4W ...

Answer (score 1):

I think the devices you are talking about are not Android Ware, but very small straight Android devices. You can find those by searching 'android watch' in any shopping site selling Chinese devices.

You can limit the screen sizes you app runs on by using `<compatible-screens>` tag but [documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/compatible-screens-element.html) suggests not to.

Removing `small` from the list of compatible screens will prohibit the app from begin installed on devices with screens smaller then about 3 inches. You can also consider using `<supports-screens>` tag described [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/compatible-screens-element.html) to enable [compatibility mode](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screen-compat-mode.html) on those devices

Comment: It is from Android Wear, as the version is 4.4W . Also, small screens are between 2 inches and ~3.5 inch, and have at least 426dp x 320dp : http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html .

Comment: Ok, so we got obvious stuff out of the way :)

Comment: Still not sure what is going on, and how come I didn't find this important information.

Comment: I thought that wear app is always packaged inside a normal one and later copied by the OS from the phone to wear device.

Comment: That's not what I did to my app, and also not what was done for the other, much more popular app. The weird thing is that the statistics say that some people still have the app installed on such devices. It's weird because it works really bad...

Comment: But to make it work on Android Wear you need to add specific module that is creating separate APK file which goes inside of "normal" one (for phone). So users are not able to install it (via Google Play) on their Android Wear if you don't create such module. So if you don't wan't users to install don't support Wear.

Comment: @Tajchert I don't understand. Can you please put a link to such an explanation? Also, how come users have done it ? Maybe just curious , power-users? How can I un-support Wear? I didn't add any special module or APK...

Comment: I think it is a reporting error, I suggest ignoring it.

Comment: To support Android Wear you need special actions - to create separate module include it in your project etc. If you didn't do anything like that it means somebody might push your APK file via ADB directly to wear (which will result in crash).

Comment: @Tajchert Please show a link about this information. Also, installing APK files doesn't count as installing via the Play store, at least for normal devices, as far as I know. Also, it doesn't crash, at least according to the developer console and according to the emulator. It just doesn't work well...

Comment: @androiddeveloper https://developer.android.com/training/building-wearables.html
https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/apps/creating.html

Comment: @Tajchert I see. So this seems like a bug. I've posted a thread about it here: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=80712

Answer (score 0):

Just delete the Wear dependency from your graddle build script on the handheld side (the line with `WearProject`) and the handheld application won't try to package/install the Wear App when it is intalled on an Android device.

Comment: I don't use Gradle. I use Eclipse, so it doesn't have it.

Comment: I'm not that familiar with ant but I think ou have the same option. The Wearable is installed because you told ant to package them both together. Delete the dependency and all should work great. If you only want to work on your Wear app and no communication is needed between the handheld and the wear, you can always try to change the package name of your wearable app to something different from your companion app, but it's only possible if your apps don't communicate together

Comment: I didn't do anything. I didn't package anything into my app. On Eclipse, everything is pretty much automatic. I'm not even sure how to develop for Android Wear on Eclipse.

Comment: Well, maybe that's your problem... Either look on the internet how to exclude the Wear app from your package with ant, or considerate migrate to Gradle and Android Studio

Comment: According to the documentation, in order to support Android Wear, I have to put an APK within the app. I didn't do such a thing, and even when extracting the exported, signed APK (which goes to the Play Store), there isn't an additional APK inside it. This leads me to the conclusion it's probably a bug on the Play Store. Another hint about it is that a very popular app doesn't support tablets, yet the statistics say that the app was installed on tablets.

Comment: Check under res/xml/ if you have a "android_wear_micro_apk.xml" file. If so, then the WearApp is added to your mobile app one way or another.

Comment: Good idea. I've done it, and there are only 3 files. All of them were made by me. None have this name.

Comment: Wild guess here, maybe it's because your Wear app has the same package name as your mobile app. But it's strange to see the Wear app installed if you did not publish it on the store...

Comment: Again, I didn't handle Android Wear at all. You can see my app on the play store for devices and tablets : https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.lb.app_manager . I didn't make any Wear app, ever. I don't even know how to do it.

Comment: Oh, I didn't understand that. You mean people can install your handheld app on an Android Wear device? Try setting `android:smallScreens` to false in your Manifest

Comment: Yes, that's what I've explained: my app wasn't intended for Android Wear. I made an app to work on all smartphones and tablets. Small screens are supported. small screens are between 2 inches (or 2.7, not sure) and ~3.5 inch, and have at least 426dp x 320dp : developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html . I've also tested it on the QVGA emulator. It works fine there.